# The loop is not adding items to lists as it supposed to

Tags: java, loops

I would like to cluster some letters based on certain value called GAD, at each iteration I would like to add the letter that has the highest value for each cluster and this will continue until no letters are left.

The problem here that code does the first iteration correct (adds the letter that has the highest value for cluster 0) and then stops, when it should find the highest letters for the next cluster.

note: the number of clusters are 4. and the variable 'clusters' is an array of objects where each object contains a list.

```
    do {
        if (count == 4) {
            count = 0;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < unassignedLetters.size(); j++) {

            if (unassignedLetters.get(j).getGADVal(count) > max) {
                max = unassignedLetters.get(j).getGADVal(count);
                maxLetter = unassignedLetters.get(j);
                System.out.println("maxLetter for cluster " + count + " is: " + maxLetter.getLetter());

            } else if (unassignedLetters.get(j).getGADVal(count) == max) {
                maxLetter = CLDMax(sheet, this.clusters[count], max, maxLetter, unassignedLetters.get(j));
            }
        }
        this.clusters[count].addLetter(maxLetter);
        unassignedLetters.remove(maxLetter);
        System.out.println("Letter " + maxLetter.getLetter() + " has been added cluster " + count);
        maxLetter = null;
        count++;
    } while (unassignedLetters.isEmpty());
```

Comment: you'll have to be more specific, especially since we have no idea what 'this.clusters[count]' is.

Comment: @Stultuske 'this' is the object that contains the array called 'clusters' that holds all the four clusters and 'count' is used to traverse through the clusters.

Comment: If there are four clusters, why are you resetting to 0 when `count == 3`? You'll be assigning to clusters 0, 1, and 2, but never the fourth cluster.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap it's double, and the code retrieves it correctly.

Comment: @dcsohl yes, you're right. Thank you!

Comment: Please note that when posting code samples, ensure that you have uniform spacing policy, otherwise many will refuse to even take a look at it and you will lose out on potential answers. It doesn't take long to run your code through a formatter.

Comment: @user4326614 well ... duh. but what type are they?

Comment: @Stultuske lol. Of type Cluster, a class I've defined. and within this class there is a list of char.

Comment: @user4326614 that is important info to share. for all we knew, clusters was an array of ints, wasn't intialized, only contained null values, ... quite a few things that can go wrong there if you don't have the entire picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `while` condition seems wrong :

```
do{   
  [...]
  for (int j = 0; j < unassignedLetters.size(); j++) {
  [...]
} while(unassignedLetters.isEmpty());
```

It should be :

```
while(!unassignedLetters.isEmpty());
```

Comment: It worked but in the second iteration it couldn't update the maxLetter and kept on treating it as a null value which caused an error, do you have how it can be solved?

Comment: @user4326614 It is hard to reproduce because I don't have the whole code. It might be related to the fact that you do not reset the variable `max` at each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

For starters your while condition is wrong.

You need `while(!unassignedLetters.isEmpty());`. read: continue executing if there are still items in unassignedLetters. 
Currently you have: continue executing if there are no items in unassignedLetters.

A do/while loop executes everything in the do{} block before it ever checks that the while condition is true. So your code will execute once, and then breaks once the while condition, `unassignedLetters.isEmpty()` evaluates to false.